# Related Content Block for a Views Page, Not a Node Page

Tags: views

I've created a views page that displays the most recent node of a certain content type. I have an image field in that content type that I would like to have displayed in the sidebar in a related content block. I have achieved this on the individual node pages using the contextual filter of NID with Content ID from URL. However, the views page is not the node page, so the related content block will not appear. How would I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You created views block which display current node images - right? What images you want to display on views page?

You can create another views block where display images from some nodes(add some term to nodes to mark them) or images from recent nodes which views shows.

Comment: The views page is essentialy the same as the node page, except that it is limited to the most recent node of a certain content type. This is so I can have a menu item that will link to the most recent node. I want the related content block to display the images related to that specific node which is being displayed as a page view. Since the user can upload an unlimited amount of images for each node, I can't limit the display of the view because I do not know how many images there are.

Comment: Create new views block which select images from recent node and place it on views page

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How would I limit the images to the most rencent node?

Comment: Views have a field option to limit multiple field values or use pager options if you display images as a separate rows